# Not able to install cx_Oracle in Anaconda Python 3.4 on my Windows 7 machine

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to connect to an Oracle instance using Python, I found that cx_Oracle is the best way for achieving the same. Since I have an Anaconda distribution of Python 3.4.3, I ran the conda package manager to install the package using the below command:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda cx_Oracle
```

However, on execution I get the below output:

```
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .........
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Generating hint:
[      COMPLETE      ]|##################################################| 100%


Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
  - cx_oracle
  - python 3.4*

Use 'conda info cx_oracle' etc. to see the dependencies for each package.

Note that the following features are enabled:
  - vc10
```

I searched on the internet and found that people have installed cx_Oracle with Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a pip install cx_Oracle and found that the actual issue was with a VC++ batch file that was not available, after installing the same cx_Oracle package got installed.